# Validate field with Html Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following field:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Title)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Title)
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

I want to make sure there is a value in the title on submit. I know you can do this by adding a required attribute on the Model, but I dont want to add required attribute to the model. Can I validate to require a value just with Html helpers?

Comment: Why don't you want to add `[Required]` to the model? Should you be using separate view models?

Comment: I dont want to add the required to the model because it might not be required in all cases. I could create a separate view model, but it would have the same fields as my current model. Would I need to create a view model just for the required attribute? That seems like over kill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [Manually validate textbox with jQuery unobtrusive validation asp.net MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353453/manually-validate-textbox-with-jquery-unobtrusive-validation-asp-net-mvc3/10353519) you could do something with jQuery like

```
$('#Title').rules('add', {
     required: true,
     messages: {
        required: 'The title field is required.'
     }
});
```

But inserting the tags manually into your html is just adding client side validation. I think its always best to have some sort of validation on your actual view model. I don't think it's overkill to do.

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    //...
}

public class ViewModel1 : BaseViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel2 : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

If the view model has different rules then it is a different view model.